# accessing object using bracket vuejs

Tags: vue.js

I have a function such that:

```
 field_validator(rule, value, callback) {
    this.form.setFieldsValue({ [rule.field]: null })
 }
```

I wasn't able to create the object like `{ rule.field: null }` and instead had to use brackets around it. Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We access an object property using `.` or `[]` notation :

```
let user={
  name:'...',
  address:{
     city:'...',
     postCode:'...'
   }
}
```

we could get access to user name using `user.name=""` or `user['name']=""`, the [] notation is useful when we want to get access to the object property dynamically, the same thing is applied on nested properties for example we could do :

```
let user={
  name:'...',
  address:{
     ['city']:'some city',
     postCode:'...'
   }
}
```

or

```
let someProp='city'
let user={
  name:'...',
  address:{
     [someProp]:'some city',
     postCode:'...'
   }
}
```

this is called [Computed Property Names](http://eloquentcode.com/computed-property-names-in-javascript#:%7E:text=Computed%20Property%20Names%20is%20an,be%20determined%20dynamically%2C%20i.e.%20computed.)